# Create a dropdown that filters the output of my repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have a repeater that lists all the products in my Products table and I need a dropdown box to filter the repeater content by category_id. I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. Here is my repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RShopItems" runat="server" ItemType="WebDevAssessment.Models.Product">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-4 productOuterContainer">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 productInnerContainer border">
                <a href='<%#"ProductDetails.aspx?item=" + Item.product_id %>' runat="server" target="_parent">
                    <img runat="server" alt='<%# Item.product_name %>' src='<%# Item.product_image1 %>'
                                    style="width: 100%" class="img-thumbnail" />
                </a>

                <h4 class="text-center"><%# Item.product_name %></h4>
                <p class="text-center">Size: <%#Item.product_size%> - $<%#Item.product_price%></p>
                <p class="features_text text-center"><%#Item.product_feat_short%></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And the behind code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using WebDevAssessment.Models;

namespace WebDevAssessment
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (WebDatabaseEntities wde = new WebDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var products = (from si in wde.Products
                                orderby si.product_price descending
                                select si).ToList();

                // assign the data to the repeater
                RShopItems.DataSource = products;

                // trigger the repeater to incorporate to display the data
                RShopItems.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can use this apporach.

In this example, we have a repeater - showing hotel names.

We have a drop down list to filter by city (no choice = all cities).

So, the mark up looks like this:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataTextField="City" DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
   <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <div style="border-style:solid;color:black;width:250px;float:left">
    <div style="padding:5px;text-align:right">

        Hotel Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotelName" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' Width="130px" />
        <br />
        First Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'  Width="130px" />
        <br />
        Last Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'  Width="130px" />
        <br />
        City: <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("City") %>'  Width="130px" />
        <br />
     </div>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

And the code to load up drop, load up Repeater, and filter looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        LoadDropDown();
        LoadGrid();
    }
}

public void LoadDropDown()
{

    // load drop down list
    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, City from tblCity ORDER BY City", 
            new SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3)))
    {
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
        DropDownList1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader;
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        // add blank row choice to drop down list
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(string.Empty, string.Empty));
    }
}

public void LoadGrid(string sFilter = "")
{
    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels", 
                  new SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3)))
    {
        if (sFilter != "")
        {
            cmdSQL.CommandText += " WHERE City = @City";
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        }

        cmdSQL.CommandText += " ORDER BY HotelName";
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
        Repeater1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadGrid(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
}
```

So it now looks like this:

[image]

So, on first load - you load up the dropdown, and the repeater.

Dropdown list has auto post back = true, and it simply filters the Repeater by applying a parameters (optional) to the data source for the repeater.

It not a lot of code, and I don't see any advantages to using linq as you are.